# How to send emails with Heroku and Gmail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gmail

I have the method in my controller `home_controller.rb`:

```
def send_letters
    if Card.created_before(Time.now).any?
      @users = User.all
      @users.each do |user|
        CardMailer.send_expired_cards(user.email).deliver_now
      end
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

And mailer for it `card_mailer.rb`:

```
class CardMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "new-cards@flashcards.com"

  def send_expired_cards(email)
    @email = email
    @url = "http://flashcards.com"

    @cards = Card.created_before(Time.now)
    mail(to: @email,
         subject: "Простроченные карточки на проверку от сайта Flashcards.com")
  end
end
```

Everything is configured to send manual letters (i just click link "Send emails" and method send_letters from controller is executed). Works fine. But I need to send these emails every day in schedule from Heroku service.

Scheduler from Heroku is pluged in my Heroku Dashboard. What I have to write in this string 
[image]
to activate `send_letters` method .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of mailer addon given in screenshot. You may find some free addon also.

[image]

Comment: I have the scheduler already. I need some command to activate send_letters action. It must be written in scheduler config. For example, `rails runner HomeController.send_letters`